# Affine connections: alternatives to the Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

When reading about the notion of affine connection, the Levi-Civita connection appears naturally as the unique affine connection that preserve the metric and is torsion free.
In this case, it is possible to express the connection coefficients analytically as a function of the metric and its derivatives.

What I am curious of are alternative affine connections, possibly admitting explicit formulas for the Christoffel symbols.

In other terms, what are other connections that agree with the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection#Formal_definition_as_a_differential_operator), but are not necessarily compatible with the metric and do rather reflect some other underlying structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a rather big story behind this. In fact, large parts of the theory of G-structures come from analyzing the set of affine connections that are compatible with a given structure. Existence of such compatible connections easily follows from the picture of principal connections. Then one studies the torsions of distinguished connections, which leads to the notion of the intrinsic torsion of a G-structure. In many important cases, one can impose a normalization condition on torsion, and then restrict to connections with normal torsion. The nice point about this story is that large parts of the behavior of a certain type of G-structures (e.g. the possible values of the intrinsic torsion, the question of existence of normalization conditions, and the size of the set of compatible connections with normalized torsion) can be determined via finite dimensional linear algebra computations. If connections with normalized torsion are unique, then theory in principle also tells you how to determine the connection from the underlying structure. Many of the examples where there are canonical connections involve a metric in some way (say for almost Hermitian structures) but there also are more exotic examples, see e.g.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01161 .